# innerHTML doesn't add form elements in firefox

Tags: innerhtml

I've looked around and see other people have had problems with innerHTML in firefox, but I can't find a solution to this. It's very simple js, and works fine in IE, but will not submit the form element outcome1 to the next page in firefox. Any firefox help is appreciated.
Thanks!
Gerald

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function addInput1(){
    var x = document.getElementById("Input1");
    x.innerHTML += "<textarea cols=\'20\' rows=\'3\' name=\'Outcome1\'></textarea><br/>";
    }

    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <form action="admin/AddNew.cfm" method="post">
            <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="center">
                <input type="button" value="+" onmousedown="addInput1();" />
                <div align="center" id="Input1"></div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

FF does not allow this long ago, just for safe.
You have to add a hidden input in the form,  and set the value before submit.

Oh, sorry. 
Maybe your condition is a little different.
Try this:
make form the first element of the body.

```
<body>
<form>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @neohope. Sorry for being a bonehead, but still not sure how to fix it. Can you hold my hand and show the code you'd use?

Comment: You fixed it @neohope. Thanks! Works perfectly.